# Navigation Item not visible in interface builder after adding segue

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, segue, uinavigationitem

I have custom UIView, that uses .xib file. I'm adding this view in storyboard inside view controller. After that I added TapGestureRecognizer to it. Then I attach segue to tap gesture recognizer (no code needed to perform segue from custom view this way).

Problem is, navigation Item is not shown in interface builder. When I build and run app, navigation is on screen and everything works like expected.

When I add segue from VC to VC, navigation bar is shown in interface builder. Why I'm getting such behavior?

[image: Segue to dummy controller]
[image: settings]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That seems like a bug in *Interface Builder* to me.

I see two possible workarounds for this situation:

1. Wire the segue from ViewController to ViewController.  Give it an *identifier*.  Call it programmatically with `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` in an `@IBAction` for your *Tap Gesture Recognizer*.  The downside of this is that you need to add code.
2. Add the *Navigation Bar* to your ViewController by setting **Attributes Inspector -> Simulated Metrics -> Top Bar** to *Translucent Navigation Bar*.  This allows you to see the *Navigation Bar* in *Interface Builder*. The downside of this is that you need to do this for every ViewController down the chain.